# Rails Rspec tests failing on Github Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, github-actions

I have the following Github Action to run my tests for my Rails app (Rails 6.1.4, Ruby 3.1.3):

```
name: Ruby CI 

on: 
  push:
    branches: [ develop, staging, master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ develop, staging, master ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options:
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Build and run test
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/test
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          PIPE_ENV: development
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
          gem install bundler:1.17.3
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
          bundle exec rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
          bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
          bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
          bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=test
```

The action seems to be working fine. The thing is that all my tests pass locally but some of them break on Github:

```
  1) CashFlow cash_flow#index returns 200
     Failure/Error: raise ParamsValidationError, errors.full_messages

     ParamsValidationError:
       missing_params
     # ./app/forms/transactions/sale_create_form.rb:52:in `save'
     # ./spec/requests/v1/cash_flow_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
```

All of my tests that have an inclusion validation fails. But if I print the received value vs the expected value right inside the class, they match! No typos, no mistakes, nothing on my side.

```
module Transactions
  class SaleCreateForm
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :organization,
                  :transaction,
                  :contact_id,
                  :products,
                  :amount,
                  :discount,
                  :concept,
                  :payment_type,
                  :payment_method,
                  :transaction_status,
                  :transaction_origin,
                  :transaction_category_id,
                  :pay_at,
                  :created_at

    validates :payment_type, :payment_method, presence: true
    validates :payment_type, inclusion: {
      in: PaymentType.pluck(:slug),
      message: :payment_type_error
    }
    validates :payment_method, inclusion: {
      in: PaymentMethod.pluck(:slug),
      message: :payment_method_error
    }

    ...
```

This is what I got inside the method that executes the validation:

```
if invalid?
    p PaymentType.pluck(:slug)
    -> ["in-cash", "credit"]

    p PaymentMethod.pluck(:slug)
    -> ["cash", "on-credit", "card", "other", "bank"]

    p @payment_type
    -> "in-cash"

    p @payment_method
    -> "cash"

    p errors.full_messages
    -> ["Payment type in-cash is not a valid payment type", "Payment method cash is not a 
    valid payment method"]
end
```

All the values I pass on the test are the expected ones, and they pass locally on my machine. I also get errors for my webmock stubs that I don't get locally:

```
expected no Exception, got #<WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST ...-7032-4fc2-b924-be77e5056b65", nil]]
```

Any hint on what I can do to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: These commands (`gem install bundler:1.17.3` and `bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3`) are redundant. See https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#bundler and https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#caching-bundle-install-automatically.

Comment: Did you try [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/) or [`rbenv`](http://rbenv.org/) to test this in a self-contained environment? What is your Ruby version installed locally? The preinstalled version is [Ruby 3.0.2p107](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#language-and-runtime) on that GHA runner. You can use the `ruby-version` of `ruby/setup-ruby` action to match it if it's different.